# Django Server - How to prevent caching on csv files?

Tags: python, django, d3.js, static

I have a server which generates some data on a daily basis. I am using D3 to visualise the data (d3.csv("path")).

The problem is I can only access the files if they are under my static_dir in the project.

However, if I put them there, they do eventually get cached and I stop seeing the updates, which is fine for css and js files but not for the underlying data.

Is there a way to put these files maybe in a different folder and prevent caching on them? Under what path will I be able to access them?

Or alternatively how would it be advisable to structure my project differently in order to maybe avoid this operation in the first place. Atm, I have a seperate process that generates the data and stores it the given folder which is independent from the server.

Many thanks,
Tony

Comment: can't you make another endpoint, which will read the file from that folder where you're storing it and render the file from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When accessing the files you can always add `?t=RANDOM` to the request in order to get a "new" data all the time.

Because the request (on the server-side) is "new" - there will be no cache, and from the client side it doesn't really matter.

To get a new random you can use `Date.now()`:

```
url = "myfile.csv?t="+Date.now()
```

Comment: I added that part.. I dont know how to force caching now to see if it actually works but hopefully it would have fixed the problem.

Comment: This code will actually as the server for a new url every time, so it's impossible for the server to cache it (unless it's specifically ignore the URL... and I guess it's not your case).

Comment: Sure! Thanks for the quick reply!